WixSharp installer. Cancel does not work in Windows 10
I am creating a plugin for outlook and have already made an installer using WixSharp. I have a problem with the installer. If I uninstall the plugin through the installer and cancel this action during the uninstall process, the plugin is still uninstalled and we get these errors in the logs:
ActionStart: Action 13:44:05: Rollback. Rolling back action: [1]
ActionData: 1: CancelRequestHandler 
ActionData: 1: Publishing product information 
Info: Information 1406. Unable to write the value AllPatches to the registry key 
\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-21-1960194858- 
3733706682-2585433926-1119\Products\723440E4DE090E344AF141C87054A4AE\Patches. Ensure 
you have the necessary permissions to the registry key or contact support.
ActionData: 1: Deleting folders Folder: [1] 
ActionData: 1: Deleting files File: [1], directory: [9] 
Info: Information 1317. An error occurred while attempting to create the folder: 
C:\Users\j.w\AppData\Local\Programs\Outlook Add-in

//large list of similar errors related to permissions, file or folder accessibility, 
and uninstallation issues.

This only happens on windows 10 and 11.
Here's the sample code:
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Condition=" (NOT Installed) " Action="SetStep" After="InstallFiles" />
  <Custom Condition=" (NOT Installed) " Action="PrepareOutlookProfile" 
   After="InstallFinalize" />
  <Custom Condition=" (NOT Installed) " Action="TunePluginResiliency" 
  After="InstallFinalize" />
  <Custom Condition=" (1) " Action="WixSharp_InitRuntime_Action" Before="AppSearch" />
  <Custom Action="Set_CancelRequestHandler_Props" Before="InstallFinalize" />
  <Custom Condition=" (1) " Action="CancelRequestHandler" 
   After="Set_CancelRequestHandler_Props" />
  <Custom Condition="1" Action="WixSharp_BeforeInstall_Action" Before="InstallFiles" />
  <Custom Condition=" (NOT Installed) " Action="Set_ARPINSTALLLOCATION" 
  After="CostFinalize" />
  <Custom Condition=" (NOT Installed) " Action="Set_ARPNOMODIFY" After="CostFinalize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

Here is the code for the custom cancel handler
void cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Shell.IsDemoMode)
      Shell.GoNext();
   else
      Shell.Cancel();
}

What do I have to do to fix this problem?
